# Polyphase filter taps for a square pulse

Tags: symbol-timing, polyphase

I'm generating Polyphase filter taps for a square pulse for symbol timing recovery. Assuming I have NFilts elements, all I do is

1. Create a basic filter
2. Interpolate by padding NFilts - 1 Zeros
3. Convolve the interpolated taps with a low-pass upsampled by NFilts
4. Partition the resulting taps into NFilts sub-filters

This seems to work very well for SRRC filters. As shown below, you can see shifted versions of the basic SRRC filter. However, when I repeat the same for square taps (a bunch of ones (equal to a number of samples per symbol), I get a filter bank with shifted versions of something else (rather than a square). Could someone explain why I don't see a shifted square when it comes to the square PFB?

[image: SRRC PFB]
[image: Square PFB]

Comment: In step 3 you're convolving with a low pass filter, that's not going to leave your pulse looking very square-like unless is has a pretty high cutoff frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the actual frequency response you really need for your "square pulse". A true square pulse requires infinite frequency, so ultimately your pulse will have a finite bandwidth and with that no longer truly be "square".

In order to interpolate with zero stuffing, you must have a transition band to implementation a realizable interpolation filter (the ideal interpolation filter is one that will pass the original passband with no distortion and completely remove the images; we approach the perfection we need based on filter complexity). The initial frequency response for the discrete time pulse will be a Dirichlet Kernel (aliased Sinc function) so will not result in a good interpolation filter once resampled using the zero-stuff and filter technique if the initial waveform only has a small number of samples per symbol. A better strategy for interpolation in that case would be to derive the filter coefficients from delayed samples (decimated and offset for each filter) of a windowed Sinc function directly, where the window duration and paramters of the Sinc function correspond to the maximum acceptable bandwidth as allowed by the given sampling rate. (Or consider using a Farrow Filter for delay correction in the timing loop).